# Measurability of a certain function

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

I have a probability space $(\Omega, M, P)$ and non-negative integrable functions on $\Omega \times [0,1]$, $F_1(\omega, t)$.

Let $X_1(\omega) = \int_a^b F_1(t,\omega) \ dt$, $0 \leq a< b \leq 1$.

Does it follow that $X_1$ is measurable with respect to 
$\sigma(G)$, where $G = \bigcup_{t \in [0,1]} F_1(t, \omega)$,
i.e. this is the smallest sigma algebra that
makes everything in $G$ measurable.

I would appreciate any hint, solutions, comments! 
Thanks!

Comment: Are there any assumptions on $M$?

Comment: @n.c not that i know of... Does it affect the result?

Comment: By Fubini $X_1$ is $M$ measurable, so if $M\subset \sigma(G)$ it would be $\sigma(G)$ as well.